# Electrostatics question inquiry

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, charge

[image]

The answer is C given that the left ball is positively charged. But since the sphere is heavily positively charged, shouldn’t the sphere repel the left positively charged ball rather than the left ball being attracted by the right?

Since the answer is C, does it mean that the attractive forces between the left and right ball are stronger than the repulsive forces between the sphere and the left ball?

Comment: Consider how the induced charges on the two small spheres are distributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easy to understand if you consider that a suspended neutral ball are conducting so they can accumulate equal and opposite charge on the surface (so that the net charge still will be zero)

Negative charge is induced on the suspended ball closer to the positively charged heavy ball. As the suspended balls are neutral so negative charge will be accumulated on the opposite side of the ball. Similarly the ball farther away is neutral now and accumulates charge opposite to that of the charge on the face of the ball closer to it i.e. the suspended ball (with positive charge) . As opposite charges attract so the balls attract.